# Plain Old XML webservice using Spring: which view technolgy?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have been writing a Plain Old XML webservice using Spring MVC. Currently I am using Freemarker to layout the XML, and that works ok.

But I'm wondering what other approaches I could look at?

Reason is that now I need to also serve up regular html and am therefore looking at the whole view layer.

Comment: Freemarker can handle HTML and XML - why do you need something new?

Comment: I know I could use freemarker for both, I'm wondering what the alternatives are.

Comment: That is what content negotiation is for and spring has a content negotiation view resolver. You can return a view and based on the content type you get either xml or html. You can then simply register 2 `FreemarkerViewResolver`s one for xml one for html.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using xsl transformations.

here is the link for the spring documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch17s05.html